# Pandas Dataframe Changing values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large Dataframe with the following columns:

The data used as the example here can be found [here](https://github.com/ENLK/Py-Projects-/blob/master/example1.csv)

```
import pandas 

x = pd.read_csv('example1_csv.)
x.head()

ID  Year    Y
22445   1991    40.0
29925   1991    43.333332
76165   1991    403.0
223725  1991    65.0
280165  1991    690.5312
```

I want to change the numbers in the column `Y` to the categories `low`, `mid`, `high`, where each category is specific to a range of numbers in `Y`:

1. `Low` replaces any number within the range of `-3000` to `600` in `Y`.
2. `Mid` replaces any number within the range of `601` to `1500` in `Y`.
3. `High` replaces any number within the range of `1501` to `17000` in `Y`.

For example, if an `ID` has a `Y` value between `-3000` and `600` then that `ID` will have the numeric value in `Y` replaced as `Low`.

How does one make these replacements? I have tried several ways but have run into `str` and `int` type errors every time. The data file used in this question is in the Github link above. Many thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `numpy.select`

```
import numpy as np
x.Y = np.select([x.Y.lt(601), x.Y.lt(1501), x.Y.lt(17000)], ['Low', 'Mid', 'High'])
```

Comment: Glad I've been of help

Answer (score 1):

This should work too.

```
x['Y'] = x['Y'].apply(lambda i : 'Low' if i > -3000 and i < 600 else ('Mid' if i >601 and i < 1500 else 'High'))
```